# my code error type Warning 1 warning C4018 and more error

Tags: c++, pointers, char

two errors:

```
1:Warning 1 warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

2:Error 2 error C3861: 'funcNewStr': identifier not found
```

how can i fix that? 
I will be happy to help you and explain where my mistake is in order for the code to work properly.
The program receives a sentence and takes the first letter from each word and composes a new string.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main(){
int size = 50;
char* ptr = new char[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    ptr[i] = NULL;
}

cout << "Enter a string: " << endl;
string str;
getline(cin, str);

for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
    ptr[i] = str[i]; 

funcNewStr(ptr, size);

system("pause");
return 0;
} 


char funcNewStr(char* ptr,int size){//my function
char* newStr = new char[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    newStr[i] = NULL;
}
newStr[0] = ptr[0];
int j = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (ptr[i] == ' '){
        newStr[j] = ptr[i + 1];
        j++;
    }
}

return *newStr;
}
```

thank's.

Comment: `funcNewStr` is defined after its first use. Move the definition above `main`.

Comment: `str.length()` can't be negative. `int i` can be.

Comment: Declare funcNewStr before main; pair new with delete.

Comment: Actually, you're better off not `new`ing or `delete`ing anything. Use std::string if not disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

`str.length()` is an `unsigned`, so you can fix the warning replacing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

by

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

And you can add a prototype of the function `funcNewStr` before the `main`:

```
char funcNewStr(char* ptr,int size);

int main(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add prototype for your function before `main()`
like this:

```
char funcNewStr(char* ptr,int size);

int main(){..}
```

Also `str.length()` is unsigned so you need to declare `i` as unsigned.

And one more thing

`using namespace std;`

is bad practice. Here's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to explanation.